# Angular UI-Grid Need to add custom row group data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

Need to display custom row data in UI grid. Template as follows
Need to display custom row data in UI grid. Template as follows

[image]
I am not able display group data in group row using UI grid.
Looking for help on this

Comment: see this if this answer helps 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31311390/angular-ui-grid-grouping-from-object

Comment: I need to display group summary data..that is difficult part

Comment: Just push your data in the object where you need to display it, or add it in Plunker then i will look into it

Comment: Identified the workaround..added group header data in every row